# Why won't app install for some Google Play users?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, game-development, google-play-console, android-developer-api

Just launched an app on google play and some users, but not all, are unable to install it. If they buy the game it just gives them the option to refund, not to install (photo linked below). Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Screenshot of the app's storefront:

[image: Screenshot of the app's storefront]